# How to configure a connection pool with Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, c3p0, dhcp

How to configure connection pooling with Spring and Hibernate?
My program as a server to listen request from Client. 
If client send request every hours, my program run normally.
But if client don't send request from 00:00 am to 07:00 am, my program catch exception.

The exception is:

> org.hibernate.TransactionException: rollback failed
>       at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.rollback(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:215)
>       at CardCharging_MemCache.dao.FilterDao.getConnectorId(FilterDao.java:123)
>       at CardCharging_MemCache.bussiness.CDVFilterRequestProcess.PCSL(CDVFilterRequestProcess.java:29)
>       at CardCharging_MemCache.myhttp.myHttphandle.handle(myHttphandle.java:113)
>       at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$DefaultExecutor.execute(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Dispatcher.handle(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Dispatcher.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: unable to rollback against JDBC connection
>       at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doRollback(JdbcTransaction.java:167)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.rollback(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:209)
>       ... 13 more
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Closed Connection
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.rollback(PhysicalConnection.java:3694)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doRollback(JdbcTransaction.java:163)
>       ... 14 more.

The exception is about connection.
Anyone help me. Plz.
Thaks!

Comment: use c3p0 api for connection pooling. and set pool size property in hibernate configuration.

Comment: show code where exception occures.

Answer (score 0):

Normal DB connection invalidate if connection is idle for certain time [8 hours in mysql default], To avoid this you just have to set these properties in your connection pool - "validationQuery", "validationInterval", "testWhileIdle", "testOnBorrow". They will live your connection during idle time and always return a valid connection from pool.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this properties in your connection pool, them should avoid session invalidation

```
<bean class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" id="dataSource" >
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>

    <property name="minIdle" value="${database.minIdle}"/>
    <property name="initialSize" value="${database.initialPoolSize}"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="${database.maxPoolSize}"/>
    <property name="maxIdle" value="${database.maxIdle}"/>
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>

    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="30000"/>
    <property name="maxWait" value="10000"/>
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="30000"/>
    <property name="logAbandoned" value="true"/>
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
    <property name="validationInterval" value="300000"/>
    <property name="jdbcInterceptors" value="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.SlowQueryReport(threshold=10000)"/>

</bean>
```

Read about the properties and their explanation [here..](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#Advanced_usage)